# Multilayer Donut plot: prettify colors/style

Tags: python, matplotlib, donut-chart

I wanted to plot some data about startups from Startup blink website.

I wanted to plot how much businesses within each subindustry are in each industry. But what I got in the some very pretty donut chart. I wanted each industry to be a specific color and each subindustry somehow be of shades of the similar color.

However some subindustries live inside different industries but this is okay.

Basically I wanted to have a nice logical coloring and also probably do something with the outter one very crowded later as well...
[image]
Here is my code from the very beggining:

```
s = requests.Session()
df = pd.DataFrame()

for p in tqdm(range(2000)):
    r = s.get(f'https://www.startupblink.com/api/entities?entity=startups&page={p}')
    d = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['page'])
    df = pd.concat([df, d], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    
df.to_csv('World_startups.csv')

# Grouping data

subindustry_global = df.groupby(['subindustry_name', 'industry_name']).count()
subindustry_global.reset_index(inplace = True)
subindustry_global.rename(columns={'title': 'Number'}, inplace=True)
# saving a dataframe to plot later
subindustry_global_donutplot = subindustry_global.sort_values('Number', ascending=False).iloc[:, :3]

# adding a columns with total number of businesses within each industry 
subindustry_global_total = subindustry_global_donutplot.groupby('industry_name').sum().reset_index()
subindustry_global_donutplot = subindustry_global_donutplot.merge(subindustry_global_total, how='outer', left_on='industry_name', right_on='industry_name', suffixes=(' in subindustry', ' in industry'))
subindustry_global_donutplot.sample(3)


# Creating lables and values lists to further plot in a donutplot

i = subindustry_global_donutplot.groupby('industry_name').sum().reset_index()
si = subindustry_global_donutplot.groupby('subindustry_name').sum().reset_index()

i_labels = i['industry_name'].values.tolist()
si_labels = si['subindustry_name'].values.tolist()

i_values = i['Number in industry'].values.tolist()
si_values = si['Number in subindustry'].values.tolist()

#
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')

pie_outer, _ = ax.pie(si_values, radius=3, labels=si_labels)
plt.setp(pie_outer, width=0.3, edgecolor='white')
 
# Second Ring (Inside)
pie_inner, _ = ax.pie(i_values, radius=3-0.3, labeldistance=.3)
plt.setp(pie_inner, width=0.4, edgecolor='white')
plt.margins(0,0)
plt.legend(i_labels)
plt.show()
```

Here I've uploaded the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/olgashevtsova/worldstartups